# What does @data actually contain in PDF::Report::Table $table_write->addTable(@data);?

Tags: perl, pdf-generation, report, cpan

I think I've got the gist of creating a table using Perl's `PDF::Report` and `PDF::Report::Table`, but am having difficulty seeing what the 2-dimensional array `@data` would look like.

The documentation says it's a 2-dimensional array, but the example on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emitti/PDF-Report-Table-1.01/lib/PDF/Report/Table.pm) just shows an array of arrays test1, test2, and so on, rather than the example showing data and formatting like `$padding` `$bgcolor_odd`, and so on.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
$main_rpt_path = "/home/ics/work/rpts/interim/mtr_prebill.rpt";

$main_rpt_pdf = 
  new PDF::Report('PageSize' => 'letter', 'PageOrientation' => 'Landscape',);

$main_rpt_tbl_wrt = 
  PDF::Report::Table->new($main_rpt_pdf);
```

Obviously, I can't pass a one dimensional array, but I have searched for examples and can only find the one in CPAN search.

Edit:

Here is how I am trying to call `addTable`:

```
$main_rpt_tbl_wrt->addTable(build_table_writer_array($pt_column_headers_ref, undef));
.
.
.

sub build_table_writer_array
# $data -- an array ref of data
# $format -- an array ref of formatting
#
# returns an array ref of a 2d array.
#

{
    my ($data, $format) = @_;

    my $out_data_table = undef;

    my @format_array = (10, 10, 0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFCC);

    $out_data_table = [[@$data],];

    return $out_data_table;
}
```

and here is the error I'm getting.

```
Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at /usr/local/share/perl5/PDF/Report/Table.pm line 88.
 at /usr/local/share/perl5/PDF/Report/Table.pm line 88
```

I cannot figure out what addTable wants for data. That is I am wondering where the formatting is supposed to go.

Edit:

It appears the addData call should look like

`$main_rpt_tbl_wrt->addTable(build_table_writer_array($pt_column_headers_ref), 10,10,xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFCC);`

not the way I've indicated.

Comment: An array of arrays is by definition a 2D Array.I don't understand the question. They gave an example for the input: `my $some_data =[ ["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test4", "test5", "test6"], ["test7", "test8", "test9"], ];$table_writer->addTable($some_data);`

Comment: Yes, my confusion is where does the formatting go? Does it go in the second array or bound to each element of each array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the module.  I tried running the example code in the SYNOPSIS, and I got the same error you get.  The module has no real tests, so it is no surprise that there would be bugs.  You can [report it on CPAN](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PDF-Report-Table).

The POD has bugs, too.

You increase your chances of getting it fixed if you look at the source code and fix it yourself with a patch.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into getting it reported.